# including a bound string object in regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

i want to match "stackover" stored in a variable x in "stackoverflow",

using perl i can do this as follows;

```
$x = "stackover";
$y = "stackoverflow";
if ($y =~ /^$x/){
    print "success";
}
```

how do i do this in python, 
i cannot have x variable in the regex

```
reg = re.compile("x")  # this will match x instead of matching stackover
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> y = 'stackoverflow'
>>> x = 'stackover'
>>> if re.match('^%s' % x, y):
...     print "success"
... 
success
```

Or

```
>>> if re.match('^{0}'.format(x), y):
...     print "success"
... 
success
```

Strictly speaking, `'^'` is unnecessary when using `.match()`, which always seeks a match at the beginning of the string. But I'm leaving it in as a placeholder for other, more complicated regexes.

Comment: Point of interest: `^` is redundant using re.match, which always starts from the beginning of the string anyway.

Comment: Quite so -- but I assume that the question was about how to substitute variables into strings. Still, I'll add a note to that effect.

Comment: so if i want to have more than two variables in regex 
then re.match('{0}{1}'.format(x,y),z) is this correct syntax?
i will use the % notaion anyway :)

Comment: You may need to use re.escape on the string you're putting into the regex in case it contains 'special' characters like "?".

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

x = 'stackover'
y = 'stackoverflow'

if re.match(x, y):
  print 'success'
```

You can compile and match as follows:

```
reg = re.compile(x)
if reg.match(y):
  print 'success'
```

Comment: oops , i feel stupid now..
actually i wanted to have x along with other regex
i mean similar to this /.?.?$x.?.?/